# Common parameter in an Union

Tags: f#, ml

Hi FSharpers (or any MLer)

Still trying to improve my Domain modeling skills (coming from OOP). Let's say that I have the following

```
type A =
| AA of AA
| AB of AB

type AA = 
{ Code : 'a
  Time : 'b }

type AB =
{ Code : 'a
  Whatsoever : 'c }
```

Let's now imagine that I want the following function signature : (A -> 'a)

To my current understanding, the solution I have is to do:

```
let f (a1:A) =
    match a1 with
    | AA a -> a.Code
    | AB a -> a.Code
```

the inconvenient with this solution is that it requires me to always add new cases to my match if I were to add some to the A union.

I imagine another solution would be a tuple-type solution (but losing the "naming" of the field):

```
type A =
| AA of AA * 'a
| AB of AB * 'a

type AA = 
{ Time : 'b }

type AB =
{ Whatsoever : 'c }

let f (a1:A) =
    snd a1
```

Is there any easy solution that I have missed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
let f (a1:A) =  snd a1
```

would not work because to get to the tuple you first need to match `AA` and `AB`.

This could work:

```
type A0<'b, 'c> =
| AA of AA<'b>
| AB of AB<'c>

type A<'a, 'b, 'c> = A0<'b, 'c> * 'a

let f (a1:A<_,_,_>) =
    snd a1
```

Your solution with `Tmp<_>` is equivalent to using a tuple.

BTW in F# the order of elements is important, in order to access type `AA` it needs be declared before type `A`. Your first example should look something like this:

```
type AA<'a, 'b> = {
  Code : 'a
  Time : 'b }

type AB<'a, 'c> = {
  Code : 'a
  Whatsoever : 'c }

type A<'a, 'b, 'c> =
| AA of AA<'a, 'b>
| AB of AB<'a, 'c>

let f (a1:A<_,_,_>) =
    match a1 with
    | AA a -> a.Code
```

Also to use generic parameters like `'a` or `'b` they need to be declared at the top:

```
type A<'a, 'b, 'c> = ...
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to put the declaration in the right order. Thanks a lot, I have understood how to make the code more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I might have an idea, using a generic type such as:

```
type A =
| AA of Tmp<AA>
| AB of Tmp<AB>

type Tmp<'T> =
{ Code : 'a
  Other : 'T }

type AA = 
{ Time : 'b }

type AB =
{ Whatsoever : 'c }
```